# Perform User Authentication if condition is true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 2 strings

```
$password_api = VSE::user('password',$username); //abc
$password     = Input::get('password'); //abc
```

---

If they're matched, I want to log the user in

```
if ( $password == $password_api ) {

    // Not sure what to do in here ... 
    $auth = Auth::attempt();
}
```

---

**Restriction:**

I don't have Laravel `user model` or a `users table`. It's all via API call.

How can I do that in Laravel 5 ?

Comment: Do you have a Laravel User model?

Comment: I'm sorry, good call. No I don't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

here i assume you have a "users" table with user data. your api username is same as the "users" table username field.

### Controller function

```
public function login()
{
$password_api = VSE::user('password',$username);
$password     = Input::get('password'); 
if ( $password == $password_api ):
  if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
  // Authentication passed...
  }
  else{
  // Authentication failed...
  }
endif;
}
```

### IF YOU DO NOT HAVE "users" TABLE.

i think the simple way is to create a session value when password matches and create a middleware/filter for that auth.

### controller function

```
public function login()
{
$password_api = VSE::user('password',$username);
$password     = Input::get('password'); 
if ( $password == $password_api ):
  Session::put('api_auth','1')
endif;
}
```

to check if user is logged in

```
if(Session::get('api_auth')==1):
//logged in
endif;
```

### Middleware creation

refer http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware for more info

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

class apiAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (Session::get('api_auth') == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            //no authentication';
            return redirect()->route('login.page')->with('error','you need to login to view the page you requested');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very precise answer ! I like it

Comment: no problem just put the question as resolved if you think it's right.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just assume you have a User model that is implementing the `Authenticatable` contract.

If that's the case you can just do the following:

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', 'johndoe'); // find by username
Auth::login($user);
```

You also don't have to assign `Auth` to a variable for this to work. After you've done the login call you can redirect the user or do whatever has to be done in your application.

Answer (score 1):

### Basic Authentication

Laravel's `Auth` provide authentication services

```
Auth::attempt([
     'username' => Input::get('username'),
     'password' => Input::get('password')
]);
```

The `attempt` method will return true if authentication was successful.

Remember to include the Auth facade at the top of the class `use Auth;`

Using `Auth` would be helpful to access the Authenticated users details through out the application

Ex: `Auth::user()->id` would get you the Auth users id anywhere in your application.

Please Refer: [Laravel Authentication Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users)

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately, I don't have a `users` table locally.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, wrong way you're going here mate - you do not want to ask a password from the API - you want to let the API validate the authentication. Send a password and username to the API and the API will tell you if you're right - then the API will log you in. I suggest you check out this oauth2 project; https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Laravel-5-Installation

Comment: Like I mention, this is just the beginning of the project, and I have to work with what I have. Right now, I just want to Auth my users in if the password is matched. I totally understand that this is not the proper way/ the right way of doing it.

Comment: Right now, everything is Hard Coded Data, Plus, I only got 2 users. I was hoping that someone can give me a little push here. I really appreciated your comment.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I have 0 experience with the auth module from laravel itself. I can't help you further. I would just check out the methods that the "Auth" class exposes. There might be something in there that you can use.